# What is EMAIL_PORT for protonmail.com mail service?

Tags: django, smtp

I tried to use https://protonmail.com email service for my django app to send notification emails. I googled and found that protonmail SMTPis 1026 and protonmail IMAP is 1143.

When I use gmail service it works fine.

My settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.protonmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@protonmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 1026
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps', 'emails')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ProtonMail Bridge says the email port should be 1025.  I attached a screenshot of my SMTP settings.

[image]

Comment: how can email host be 127.0.0.1 when we are connecting to a remote smtp server ?

Comment: @ShantanuBedajna, because using the ProtonMail SMTP Bridge you're actually connecting to your localhost:1025 first (which is managed by Bridge) and then, through the Bridge, to the actual ProtonMail service.